# TypeError: clipBoard.createTextRange is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am using

```
function CopyToClipBoard()
{
  clipBoard = document.getElementById('copyTemp'); 
  clipBoard.innerText = document.getElementById('copyFrom').value; 
  CopiedText = clipBoard.createTextRange(); 
  CopiedText.execCommand("Copy"); 
  clipBoard.innerText = ""; 
}
```

for copying a text from browser. 
On click I need to copy.

```
    <textarea id="copyTemp" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"><?php echo $memMobile; ?></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="copyFrom" value="<?php echo $memMobile; ?>">
<input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="CopyToClipBoard()">
```

then

```
TypeError: clipBoard.createTextRange is not a function
```

error is coming

Comment: Unless you're declaring `clipBoard` somewhere, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). It's not why you're having the problem, but seemed worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `createTextRange` is an [MS-only extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's not on the standard [`HTMLTextAreaElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmltextareaelement) or [`HTMLElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#htmlelement). There is a [`createRange`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level2-DocumentRange-method-createRange) on `document`.

For cross-browser range stuff, you might look at Tim Down's [`rangy`](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/).